# "Apps that include an arm64 are required to include to include both armv7 and armv7s architecture" Error in application loader

Tags: ios, application-loader

I am trying to submit an application via the application loader. I get this error. But I already checked in the build settings and all three architectures are included in the Valid Architectures settings.

Comment: valid archtictures is fine but what about the architectures field?

Comment: and you can check the architectures with the commandline tool `lipo` if you think the uploader is wrong

Comment: its the same, includes all three architectures.

Comment: @Daij-Djan how can i use lipo?

Comment: in terminal type: `lipa -info %PATH_TO_YOUR_EXECUTABLE'

Comment: the executable is in your app.

Comment: here what it returns: non fat file, application is arm64! does that mean that the application loader is wrong?

Comment: no ;) it means it is right - there is no armv7 and no armv7s

Comment: maybe share the project file at least... you only build for armv64

Comment: @Daij-Djan Legaly i cant share the files, im working for a client under a contract that requires the project not to be shared anywhere :( do u think removing the armv7 and armv7s will solve the problem?

Comment: no. only the 5s on ios7 has arm64 so you need armv7

Comment: try setting up a new app, compile it, check it with lipo and then 'spot the differences' in the settings

Comment: @Daij-Djan I had another project that i just submitted for review. It has exactly the same settings but in lipo it says that it includes all three architectures! Is there a way to add the architectures manually?

Comment: you have to figure out why your xcode for thisapp doesnt compile them

Comment: you can use lipo to combine N executables of different architecutre but you have to HAVE those in the first place.

Answer (score 28):

Disconnect any device and just leave the option in "iOS Device" and archive it.

Comment: i'd love to know why that works (when previously i'd been able to still archive with device intact), but for now, it has solved my problem, therefore grateful.

Comment: Hi Jon. I'm sorry I don't have the answer for that, I was just struggling with my archive and then I realized that just the arch for the 5s (the model of my device) was been included and so I tried disconnecting and it worked. I'm glad that it solved your problem.

Comment: It is because of the comment made by Alfahad. When your device is plugged in it is building for the active architecture (i.e. your device). When you unplug your device or change the build active architecture only to 'NO' it fixes this issue.

Answer (score 25):

Change 'Build Active Architecture Only' to 'NO'