# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am working on a project in Xcode 6.3.1 and wanted to submit a build on iTunes connect. Saw the steps from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html) and it said 'apps that include `arm64` are required to include `armv7 architecture`'. Further research upon this issue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421234/apps-that-include-an-arm64-are-required-to-include-to-include-both-armv7-and-ar) made me set `Build Active Architecture` to `No`.

Now, my project has 6 build errors :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONRequestSerializer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AddViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AddViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FAKFontAwesome", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MyProfileViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in LikeTableViewCell.o
  objc-class-ref in DetailsViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in UserProfileViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in CTableViewCell.o
  objc-class-ref in TakeTheCViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in NTableViewCell.o
  ...
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_JGProgressHUD", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in BaseViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_DTAlertView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MyProfileViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in CDetailsViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in CSolutionTableViewCell.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried updating all these frameworks in my pods file but the errors remain. Tried to add them to my project by dragging the files to my project(which also prompted more errors because of duplicity that I managed to resolve by removing the frameworks from the Pods file) but then I will have to change all my import statements (if I'm right).

Any help with all this? And pardon me if I sound stupid, still new to iOS development.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Comment: I had come through that link as well.. Checking all the steps again

Comment: I tried restarting Xcode and now my Pod file is gone

Comment: Make sure you are opening the workspace file, and not the Xcode project file. The workspace will contain your project and the Pods project.

Comment: Yup thanks.. Worked when I opened the workspace file...

Comment: The main problem still remains.. If there is anything else you all want me to mention here, please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Figured a way out.. Rather than setting    `Build Active Architecture` to    `No` , I removed all my devices from the machine and then archived the build. It went smoothly without any errors. But still, if anyone has a solution to the problem mentioned above, please post so others know.