# xamarin ios release - Apps that include an arm64 architecture are required to include an armv7

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, release

I'm trying to upload ipa file, coded using Xamarin built from Visual Studio. Meet this architecture error.

There're some suggestion here in xcode, but how to do this in Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio ?
["Apps that include an arm64 are required to include to include both armv7 and armv7s architecture" Error in applicaiton loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421234/apps-that-include-an-arm64-are-required-to-include-to-include-both-armv7-and-ar)

Here is my configurations:
[vs config1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDzFI.jpg),
[vs config 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1dpw.jpg)

Does anyone know how to achieve this without enable "ARMV7" ?

[Updates]
I was thinking to make app support only iPhone5 and above, but seems this rejected while upload ipa.
I've succeed to upload by setting to build with "ARMv7, ARMv7s, ARM64" setting.
Thank you guys for quick reply!

Answer (score 7):

The issue here is that in your first image you can see the `Supported architectures` listed as `ARMv7s + ARM64`. `ARMv7s` is not the same as `ARMv7` - it is a derivative that can only run on ARM CPUs that support it. In the case of iPhones, this would be the iPhone 5 and newer.

`ARMv7s` support is not required by Apple, and generally there is no need to include it in your app unless you are using any of the, very specific, optimisations it brings.

You just need to use the dropdown to change this to `ARMv7 + ARM64` and you will be able to submit your app successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to edit the relevant Build Configuration in your iOS csproj file.

I mainly use Xamarin Studio though so I can't guide you in the Visual Studio menus, but if you can't find it in the Visual Studio properties of the csproj file, this is what my Release build configuration looks like:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|iPhone' ">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\iPhone\Release</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants></DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
    <MtouchArch>ARMv7, ARM64</MtouchArch>
    <MtouchI18n>
    </MtouchI18n>
    <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
    <MtouchUseRefCounting>true</MtouchUseRefCounting>
    <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution</CodesignKey>
    <IpaPackageName>
    </IpaPackageName>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

So the important part to edit is:

```
    <MtouchArch>ARMv7, ARM64</MtouchArch>
```